# Occurrence of a number in a range of other numbers

Tags: php

There is an array with numbers:

```
$array1 = [200, 400, 600, 800, 1500];
```

And there is a second array :

```
$array2 = [50, 150, 250, 600, 900, 2000];
```

How to create ranges from $array1 like this:

```
$range = [
          range[1, 200],
          range[201, 400],
          range[401, 600],
          range[601, 800],
          range[801, 1500],
          range[1501, 99999] //99999 - as maximum allowed value
];
```

And how to check which of these ranges includes each element from $array2?
Ex:

> 50 in array 1 - 200 ($range[0])

My attemps to find solution:

```
 $max = max($array1);
 $min = min($array1);
    
    foreach($array2 as $a) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) 
         {
            if ($a < $max AND $a > $min)
              {
                $n[$a] = range($min, $array1[$i]);
  
            } elseif ($a > $max) {
                $n[$a] = range($array1[$i], 999999);
               
            } elseif ($p < $min) {
                $n[$a] = range(1, $array1[$i]);
              } else {

                $n[$a] = "Out of range";
            }
        }
    }
```

But it will work for three numbers, and if there are more...

```
Desired result:

50 in 1 - 200
150 in 201 - 400
250 in 201 - 400
600 in 401 - 600
900 in 801 - 1500
2000 in 1501 - 99999
```

Comment: Where is your attempt at solving your problem?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`? There is no JavaScript code in your question.

Comment: How does the desired output relate to your inputs? What is the role of the second input array? Why is there no `401-600` range in the desired output? How is the number 50 or 2000 from the second array used in the output?

Comment: fixed
add 401-600 in array

Comment: please add the wanted result (data structure/values).

Comment: Desired result:

50 in 1 - 200
150 in 201 - 400
250 in 201 - 400
600 in 401 - 600
900 in 801 - 1500
2000 in 1501 - 99999

Comment: Surely 150 should be in 1 - 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PHP is too rusty to give that a go unfortunately. Here's a JS version though:

```js
const array1 = [200, 400, 600, 800, 1500];
const array2 = [50, 150, 250, 600, 900, 2000];

const ranges = array1
  .concat(array1[array1.length - 1] < 99999 ? 99999 : [])
  .reduce((acc, val, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => {
    if(!prev && val === 1) return acc;
    const start = (!prev && val !== 1) || prev === 1 ? 1 : prev + 1;
    acc.push([start, val]);
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log('ranges', JSON.stringify( ranges ));

const find_range = (num) =>
  ranges.find(([start, end]) => start <= num && end >= num);

const res = array2.map((num) => {
  const [start, end] = find_range(num);
  return num + ' in ' + start + ' - ' + end;
});

console.log(res.join("\n"));
```

I've assumed that you don't need a range array like the one that PHP's range function would give you and that a two value array listing the start and end of the range is sufficient.

`.concat(array1[array1.length - 1] < 99999 ? 99999 : [])` checks to see if the last value of the array is less than 99999 and adds 99999 to the array that we run reduce over if it is.

If you're not familar with it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)'s a description of how reduce works. (PHP equivalent (I think): [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).) Of particular note is `{ [i - 1]: prev }` as part of the argument list. It is simply extracting the previous item in the array from the one that we're currently working with.

Does that look like what you were trying to achieve?

**EDIT:** should I delete this now that JS is no longer asked for in the question?

Comment: do not delete this solution. it is very useful